# Auto complete for php jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

I have problem with autocomplete search form script using codeigniter, jquery.

Here is my script:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response)
  {
    var name=$('#tags').val(); // get value from input field search
    $.ajax({
        url: "phone/search", // call to my controller phone, method search
        dataType: "json", // expect datatype return as json
        data: "name="+name,
        success: function(data) {
          response(data.phone_name);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

phone/search

```
public function search()
{
    $b=array();
    $name=$this->input->post('name');

    $results=$this->phone->search($name); // my modal phoneShop_m.php alias as phone

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $b['phone_name']=$result->phone_name;
    }

    echo json_encode($b);       
}
```

my model:

```
public function search($name){
    $this->db->like('phone_name',$name);
    return $this->db->get('phone')->result_object();
}
```

My form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tags" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

However, it does not autocomplete when I type some words in search form.

Comment: Check your console for errors???

Comment: Try with `data: { name: name },`

Comment: url should be `url: "<?php echo base_url()?>phone/search",`

Comment: Also method should be provided: `method: "POST",`. [Here is full documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for using jQuery AJAX.

Comment: I just followed, it does not work

Comment: @Saty, following all suggestions,  I tried firebug console i can see the response result, but why not see it autocomplete at my search form?